# Determining the value of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I know that $Log(z) = \ln|z| + i \arg(z)$, and that to make this functions "nice" in some sense, (single valued, holomorphic) we need to pick a branch. The argument function is the one that causes trouble, since it is multivalued, and hence it needs to be specified. The standard branch is the one that makes $Log(1)=0$, $Log(i)=i(\pi/2)$ etc.

As far as I understand, this argument function is also dependent on some ray (or more generally, a curve connecting 0 and infinity), and the standard case is again to pick the positive real axis. My question is, what happens if I want to define the logarithm by picking the same branch, but taking some weird curve, like a spiral as shown in the picture below?

What would $Log(e)$ be equal to for in this case? Clearly it would be $1+ i \arg(z)$, but what is $\arg(z)$ here?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have not actually defined your function

Comment: You mean the one generating the curve? Well in my exercise sheet, we just have some abstract spiral without any explicit formula... @FShrike

Comment: If I interpret your diagram correctly, the argument of $e$ is here defined to be $2\pi$. However, it is unclear

Comment: I do agree with you, but am not sure how to rigorously write it @FShrike

Comment: I suppose the definition is: the argument of a point $(x,y)$ is the sum of its principal argument with $2\pi n$, where $n$ is the number of times the ray crosses a red line. With this, the defined argument for $e$ is $2\pi$

Comment: Not sure if I follow. Under your definition, the argument of -4 for instance would be $3  \pi$, of 5 $4  \pi$ and so on, right?

Comment: This is just my interpretation. It's up to you and your teachers to actually figure out what the question is... but I think this is how the diagram is supposed to be read. Argument of $-4$ would be $5\pi$ I believe, and of $5$ would be $4\pi$ (the principal value of arg $-1$ is $\pi$ not $-\pi$) (by most conventions) (it's arbitrary, after all...)